# Multiple string conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMz60.png)

I want to validate the existence of a substring in column 'description'. If 'true', write something in column 'result'.
My code works if I have one condition

```
df.loc[df.index[df.description.str.contains('ab',flags=re.I, regex=True)],'result']='found ab'
```

and,

```
df.loc[df.index[df.description.str.contains('d|f',flags=re.I, regex=True)],'result']='found d or f'
```

but does not work for an 'and' condition

```
df.loc[df.index[df.description.str.contains('d&f',flags=re.I, regex=True)],'result']='found d and f'
```

It works if I write like this, but too lengthy,

```
df.loc[(df.index[df.description.str.contains('d',flags=re.I, regex=True)] & df.index[df.description.str.contains('f',flags=re.I, regex=True))] ,'result']='found d&f'
```

As lastly, is there a better code for following condition?

```
.contains(l)&.contains(o)|.contains(m)&.contains(n)
```

Comment: Have a try at this - ```df['description'].apply(lambda x: re.compile("[l|o|m|n]"))```

Comment: Could you provide with the complete script to replicate your problem?

Answer (score 1):

To match an `AND` condition you can use the following regex:

```
(?:d)\w*f|(?:f)\w*d
```

**Details:**

- `(?:d)` : Non-capturing group - matches the character `d` literally
- `\w*` : 0+ letters/digits/underscores
- `f` : matches the character `f` literally
- `|` : or (alternative to find when `f` is preceding `d`)
- `(?:f)` : Non-capturing group - matches the character `f` literally
- `\w*` : 0+ letters/digits/underscores
- `d` : matches the character `d` literally

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"description": ["abc", "def", "hjk", "lmno", "dxx", "fxx", "fxd"]}
)

reg_list = [
    ("ab", "found ab"),
    ("d|f", "found d OR f"),
    ("(?:d)\w*f|(?:f)\w*d", "found d AND f"),
    ("l|m|n|o", "found l|m|n|o"),
]

for r in reg_list:
    df.loc[df.index[df.description.str.contains(r[0], flags=re.I, regex=True)], 'result'] = r[1]

print(df)
```

```
  description         result
0         abc       found ab
1         def  found d AND f
2         hjk            NaN
3        lmno  found l|m|n|o
4         dxx   found d OR f
5         fxx   found d OR f
6         fxd  found d AND f
```